# GO lang syntax error: unexpected name, expecting )

Tags: go

I have started learning **Go lang** recently.I have spend couple of hours but can't figure out what's wrong with this.

**Here is my code:**

```
func preference(cc *core.ComponentContext, w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){

userID, err := core.PostParam(req, "user_id")
key, err := core.PostParam(req, "key")
value, err := core.PostParam(req, "value")  
if err != nil {
    cc.Error("Error reading the user id:", err.Error())
    msg := fmt.Sprintf("user_id: %s", err.Error())
    http.Error(w, msg, http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

// compile time error on below line
response := models.UserPrefer(cc, userID int64, key string, value string)

b, err := json.Marshal(response)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Internal Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
fmt.Fprintf(w, string(b[:]))
```

}

Following error is throw **syntax error: unexpected name, expecting )**
it's probably simple, but with my limited knowledge in Go lang I can't figure out.

Comment: Why do you have the type names `int64` and `string` in the call to `UserPrefer`?

Comment: At what line is the error thrown?

Comment: @AjPennster. in code i have mention compile time error. any reason of down voting ?

Comment: Don't edit out the errors that your question is about. If someone else reads this, the answers and comments are no longer going to make sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are passing types when calling methods

Use

```
response :=models.UserPrefer(cc, userID, key, value)
```

instead of

```
response :=models.UserPrefer(cc, userID int64, key string, value string)
```

Answer (score 2):

While calling a function just pass the parameter. You do not need to pass the type of parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I got an error very similar to this when I forgot to put in a colon while instantiating a type. Created a minimum example to illustrate.

> prog.go:11:12: syntax error: unexpected literal "Sedimentary", expecting comma or }

https://play.golang.org/p/QKmcOHnsF7C

In this example, I just needed to add a colon after the attribute name.

```
r := Rock{
    RockType:   "Sedimentary", // the ":" was missing, and is in the go play link above
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because I was using a `reserved` keyword as an argument name for a method.

Code snippet that was throwing this error:

```
func setCustomTypeData(set bson.M, type string) {

}
```

Code snippet that fixed this issue:

```
func setCustomTypeData(set bson.M, customManagedType string) {

}
```